# Would like to use Diazo with Plone 3

Tags: plone, diazo, plone-3.x

I'd like advice on the best approach to deploying Diazo to work with Plone 3. I know that plone.app.theming is out of the question for versions less than Plone 4.1 but we can't upgrade to Plone 4 yet as we need to port some code to Plone 4.x first but we'd like to benefit from the theming infrastructure of Diazo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also run Diazo via any of the non-Plone deployment methods listed at http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/deployment.html.  You'll lose all of the Plone TTW integration, but if you can build and compile your themes by hand, you're all set.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think using diazo compiler + mod xslt is the best bet for me on this project.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a very sensible way to go.  I'd much rather do that than try to backport features into older versions of XDV.

Answer (score 1):

plone.app.theming requires Plone 4.1. You may be able to use its predecessor, collective.xdv.

[collective.xdv Installation documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.xdv#installation)

Comment: With collective.xdv, do I lose some of the newer stuff like the 'before', 'after' and css:theme-children rules?

Comment: You do. As xdv is just an older version of diazo, you could probably retrofit diazo into collective.xdv without too much effort.

Comment: I think the diazo compiler + mod xslt is the best bet in this case. Aiming at the most pragmatic approach.